# Sockets, sent pdf file always arrives zero bytes size

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I'm sending a pdf file from android tablet client to Java app running on Windows 7. The file always arrives as a size of zero bytes. what is the problem here?

Before the pdf file was sent from client to server, the size of the file as long value is sent from client to server,  this size is correct and always arrives to the server.  For the pdf file, I'm using for this test the size is 566718 bytes.

How can I get the pdf file to arrive as the correct size?

Server code

```
 public class Server {
 ServerSocket serverSocket;
 Socket socket;
 boolean runner = true;

Server() throws IOException{

    serverRunner();
    System.out.println("server constructor started");

} // Server() constructor

public void serverRunner() throws IOException {

    System.out.println("serverrunner started");

     try {

      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6789, 100);

      runner = true;

        while (runner) {

            socket = serverSocket.accept();

            MultiThreader multi = new MultiThreader(socket);
            Thread t = new Thread(multi);
            t.start();

        }  // while runner
       } catch (IOException ex) {

    }

 } // serverRunner()

 } // class Server


public class MultiThreader implements Runnable {
Socket socket;
public int fileSizeFromClient;
FileOutputStream fos = null;
BufferedInputStream bis = null;
BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
DataInputStream dis = null;
DataOutputStream dos = null;

public MultiThreader(Socket socket){
    System.out.println("print out from multithreader class");
    this.socket = socket;

} // multiThreader

@Override
public void run() {

    System.out.println("multi threader started");

    // action #1 read file from client =====================================
    // transfer.pdf read this file sent from android device to this computer

    int bufferSize = 0;

    try {

     bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
     dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

     fileSizeFromClient = dis.readInt();
     System.out.println("file size from client is " + fileSizeFromClient);

      File fileDirectory = new File("C:/DOWNLOAD/");
        if (!fileDirectory.exists()) {
            fileDirectory.mkdir();
      }
      File file = new File("C:/DOWNLOAD/transfer.pdf");
      file.createNewFile();

       fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
       bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
       dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

       byte[] buffer = new byte[fileSizeFromClient];

      int totalBytesRead = 0;

        while(totalBytesRead < fileSizeFromClient){
            int bytesRemaining = fileSizeFromClient = totalBytesRead;
            int bytesRead = dis.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, bytesRemaining));
            if(bytesRead == -1) {
                break;
            } else {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); 
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            }
        } // while

      } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MultiThreader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } finally {
        try {
          //  socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MultiThreader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

} // run

} // MultiThreader
```

client code

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {

TextView textViewOne;
Button buttonOne;
Socket socket;
private String serverIP = "192.XXX.X.X";
FileInputStream fis;
FileOutputStream fos;
private File file;
DataInputStream dis;
DataOutputStream dos;
BufferedInputStream bis;
BufferedOutputStream bos;
long length;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   textViewOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

   buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Thread myThread = new Thread(MainActivity.this);
        myThread.start();

    }

   });

} // oncreate

@Override
public void run() {

    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
           textViewOne.setText("run method started");
        }
        });

    try {
        socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 6789);

        if (socket == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   textViewOne.setText("connected");
                }
                });

        }

        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "transfer.pdf");

        length = file.length();

        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

        dos.writeInt((int) length); // sends the length as number bytes is file size

        int count = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) length];

        while ((count = bis.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }

        bos.flush();
        bis.close();
        socket.close();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

 } // mainactivity
```

Comment: Are there any exceptions logged? Why aren't you closing the output streams on the server? Have you tried adding diagnostics in the copying loop?

Comment: You don't need to call createNewFile(), but you do need to close your output streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem, I believe.

```
int bytesRemaining = fileSizeFromClient = totalBytesRead;
```

That's doing two assignments, so you're assigning 0 to `fileSizeFromClient` immediately, and exiting the loop.

You meant:

```
int bytesRemaining = fileSizeFromClient - totalBytesRead;
```

That's a pretty subtle typo, and you were unlucky that it's a typo which still resulted in valid code :(

Given that you're closing the socket immediately anyway though, it's not clear why you're sending the file size first. Your code could be simpler if you just had the same "copy from an input stream to an output stream until the input runs out of data" at both the client and the server, just from a `FileInputStream` to a `Socket`'s `OutputStream` at the client, and the `Socket`'s `InputStream` to a `FileOutputStream` (possibly with a buffering wrapper) at the server.

I'd also recommend closing *all* streams - if you're using Java 7, you can do this simply using a try-with-resources statement; in earlier versions you should close streams in `finally` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

**-** By **rule of thumb**, always **close the Streams after writing/reading to and from it**.

**-** Close the Stream at **Server side**.

**-** Use `Socket` with `InputStream` and `Scanner` for hassle free data transfer between socket. (Thats what i felt, experimenting with sockets.)

Comment: I would definitely *avoid* using `Scanner` here. There's absolutely no need for it here.

Comment: Mr.Skeet, i have tried the combination of Scanner, InputStream and InputStreamReader... and i didnt felt it working for me couple of times... and when i tried the combination of Socket, InputStream and Scanner it went bang on the target... I am a big fan of your... i would love to rectify my mistake of using Scanner if you can please let me know its ill effects. I would be obliged

Comment: Well you we can't really tell what you were doing wrong when you *weren't* using `Scanner`, although if you were using `InputStreamReader` on non-text data, that would be a problem. But I've seen *numerous* issues with the `Scanner` API not behaving as expected, whereas for just transferring data, the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` API is very simple indeed.

Comment: I mean will this create a problem if i use it `Scanner reader = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());`

Comment: Quite possibly not, but it adds complication for no obvious benefit, when you're *just* trying to copy data from one stream to another.

Comment: Ok Mr.Skeet ... thank you very much for this tip.. i will keep this in mind when next time i will code socket.

Comment: The file here is a PDF. Neither a Scanner nor a Reader can possibly be used for this purpose. They are for text. This is binary data. -1